# Mean Average Precision is equal to -1 while tranining custom object detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

[tensorboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F07tm.png)
I am using the TensorFlow object detection API to detect my custom object. I train the model 16k steps. The loss rate continued to decrease steadily until 0.28. After finishing the training, I test the model but the model didn't draw anything around the object.  I did these steps very carefully:

1-) Resize the image to 300x300
2-) Label the all image
3-) I divide the data %80 training, %20 test image.
4-) I apply the path regulator on this file and I made sure the file path is correct. 
5-) I convert the xml files to csv files.
6-) I created a label_map.pbtxt file and format was like this:

```
item {
  id: 1
  name: '30'
}

item {
  id: 2
  name: '40'
}

item {
  id: 3
  name: '50'
}

item {
  id: 4
  name: '60'
}

item {
  id: 5
  name: '70'
}

item {
  id: 6
  name: 'pedestrian'
}

item {
  id: 7
  name: 'girilmez'
}

item {
  id: 8
  name: 'go_right'
```

7-) I added to this code in generate_tfrecord.py :

```
if row_label=='30':
        return 1
....
else:
     return 0
```

8-) I Modify the ssd config just these parameters:

```
num_classes: 8
num_examples: 550
```

9-) Generate the tf record

My test result is like this :
[test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNZ1E.png)
Nothing is drawn around the object.

Any idea what is the problem? Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Is the tfrecord file made correctly? you can check your annotations by using tfrecord-viewer. https://github.com/sulc/tfrecord-viewer

Comment: Sorry for late answer. I fixed that problem.